# get textbox value from php

Tags: php, string, email, forms

I'm trying to create am online application for some job postings we have at work.

I have the form items (text boxes / drop downs /etc) portion set up and i have the send email with a captcha part setup

im unclear on how to "call" the value of something like

```
<select name="education">
        <option value="None">None</option>
        <option value="HighSchool">HighSchool</option>
        <option value="BA/BS">BA/BS</option>
        <option value="MA/MS">MA/MS</option>
        <option value="MBA">MBA</option>
        <option value="Ph.D">Ph.D</option>
        <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
```

In the mail portion of the code how do insert the value of the education dropdown into the body?

```
            $to = "rbarbro@markonsolutions.com";
            $subject = "Test mail";
            $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
            $from = "someonelse@example.com";
            $headers = "From: jobs@markonsolutions.com";
            mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
            echo "Mail Sent.";
```

actuall page is located here

http://www.markonsolutions.com/captcha.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$message = "Education: " . $_POST["education"];
```

Make sure to sanitize your form posts though, otherwise people could inject JavaScript or whatever they want into your form.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you might be confused about how PHP works. PHP is a serverside language, which means that you can't receive the values of those fields in PHP until a page is loaded from the server. Usually this happens when the user presses the submit button. Now, the page that is loaded might *incidentally* be the same page that the form is on, but it's not a requirement.

Once a page with a form is submitted, in the request data, it sends along all the values that the user chose. You can access these values in PHP using $_GET and $_POST arrays, which you can find more about here:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm

Sorry if I misunderstood your question, but I think its useful to clarify this for people who visit that might be confused about the difference between serverside and clientside.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the user submit the form, and then get the value from the `$_POST["education"]` (or `$_GET["education"]`) fields depending upon what method you choose.

Answer (score 1):

$message = "Here goes my mail body:
Education selected was: {$_POST['education']}

Here is another one: {$_POST['Jobname']}
";

In my opinion, you should capture all individual post, do some checks and create a little template.

```
$body = sprintf("Name: %s
Job: %s
", $name
 , $phone);
```

Well, i think i have told too much about the subject of the this topic.